# Find all continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^2=f$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let ($X,\mathcal{T}$) be a topological space. Find all continuous
>   functions $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^2=f$.

[ **Note** after the discussion in the comments: $f^2$ is the function $f^2:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $(f^2)(x)=(f(x))^2$ for every $x\in X$. ]

The hypothesis gives us that $f=0$ or $f=1$.

At what points of $X$ will $f$ take the value $1$?

Comment: $f^2$ is $f\circ f$ ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM yes.

Comment: Is $f^2=f(f)$ or $f.f$ .

Comment: $f\circ f$ does not make sense unless $f(X)\subset X$

Comment: "@LeGrandDODOM yes." No it is not. Obviously not. The function $f\circ f$ is not even defined if $f:X\to\mathbb R$ and $X$ does not contain $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Did If $f^2=f(f)$, isn't it again undefined in the case of $\mathbb{R}\not\subseteq X$?

Comment: @ioanna202 What? For every set $X$ and every function $f:X\to\mathbb R$, the function $f^2:X\to\mathbb R$ exists and is defined by $(f^2)(x)=(f(x))^2$ for every $x$ in $X$.

Comment: @Did Excuse me you are right, I thought that $f(f)$ equals $f(f(x))$ which is the same as $f\circ f$.

Comment: $f$ assumes only the values $0$ and $1$. Their respective preimages are clopen in $X$. If $C$ is clopen, its characteristic function is a solution. SO the number of solutions is exactly the number of clopen subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 6):

$$f^2=f\iff f(f-1)=0\iff f=0\text{ or }f= 1.$$

Such functions are in bijection with the partitions of your space into two unions of connected components.

Comment: This is not quite true, because in general a union of connected components might not be open or closed, whereas if $f$ is a continuous function taking on only the values $0$ and $1$, then $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(1)$ are both open and closed.

Comment: LIke I said in my comment, the solutions are exactly the characteristic functions of clopen subsets of $X$.